# $.each() iterating over characters in a string - do I need to eval()?

Tags: jquery, json, eval, jsonp

I have json data being returned as a collection:

```
var foo = ["6", "7", "33"]
```

using JSONP in jQuery.  Since I'm using JSONP, the data is being returned to a callback function, which is interpreting it as a string instead of a collection.  Do I need to run `eval(foo)` on the string in the callback before handling it as a collection, or is there some other means of recasting it?

Comment: Note that using `eval` is a potential security risk. Follow bcherry's suggestion to keep your script secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you should be doing `.ajax` with `dataType: "jsonp"`, which should send the parsed data to your callback, rather than a string.  If this doesn't work for you, or there are other complexities I'm not seeing, you can use `$.parseJSON(foo)` instead of `eval(foo)`.  This will call the browser's native `JSON.parse` method if it exists, or use `eval` if it doesn't.